# Spring Boot Context Path for WebJars in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

If i build a `war` file and deploy it on tomcat, it cannot find the webjars which i have written in `index.html` as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
```

so, had to manually change the `src="{my_application_name}/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"`

Is there a way i can do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

When you point any path preceding with `/` using `src` tag, it will take absolute path and your request will be redirected to `localhost:[port]/whatever_path_is`.

So I suggest you to use relative path without `/` like below :

```
src="path_to_your_js_files"
```

Comment: tried like `src="webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"`. Does not work.

Comment: Can you check request in your browser's console.?

Comment: Checked in chrome with `f12` and it shows in `red` with message `not found`. If i manually add the context path it finds ok.